# Chef: modify existing resource

Tags: chef-infra

My current script looks like:

```
es_conf = elasticsearch_configure 'elasticsearch' do
    allocated_memory '512m'
    configuration ({
        'http.port' => port,
            'cluster.name' => cluster_name,
            'node.name' => node_name,
            'bootstrap.memory_lock' => false,
            'discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes' => 1
    })
end
es_conf.path_data data_location if data_location

elasticsearch_plugin 'repository-s3' do
  action :install
end

elasticsearch_plugin 'x-pack' do
  action :install
end

elasticsearch_configure 'elasticsearch' do
    configuration ({
        'http.port' => port,
        'cluster.name' => cluster_name,
        'node.name' => node_name,
        'bootstrap.memory_lock' => false,
        'discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes' => 1,

        'xpack.monitoring.enabled' => true,
        'xpack.graph.enabled' => false,
        'xpack.watcher.enabled' => true
    })
end
```

It's currently working to me (I mean it configures elasticsearch as I want). Nevertheless, I'm aware it's not so fine enought. I mean, I'm using `elasticsearch_configure` twice. The problem is I first need to configure elasticsearch, then I need to install `x-pack` and then configuring elasticsearch with specific `x-pack` values.

Any ideas in order to do it a bit more elegant?

Exactly, I mean how should I change `es_conf`?

Comment: Can't you install the plugin the invoke and then invoke `elasticsearch_configure` with all the settings?
Also, not related to the question, why don't you use an attribute containing the configuration hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the second resource will truly be a separate resource, not a modification of the first. In Chef 12 it will "clone" the state of the first, but in Chef 13 the two are entirely unrelated other than sharing a name.

The general purpose fix for this would be to use `edit_resource` but since you already have the resource object locally you could do this:

```
es_conf.configuration.update({new: keys, go: here})
```

Comment: Noah (aka coderanger) is too humble. His explanation of edit_resource is basically the only one that is decently in depth I can find on the internet including the chef docs and stack overflow. See https://coderanger.net/rewind/ for more details.